# how to embed weld into jetty 9 to have cdi in my java maven project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, weld

I have a JEE7 project using CDI.
I want to test that project on Jetty 9, which implements Java EE 7 Web Profile.

The following link indicate that we can plug Weld into Jetty, but how ?
Thanks

**EDIT:** 
And, how do that with jetty-maven-plugin ?

[Jetty and Java EE 7 Web Profile](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-javaee.html#webprofile-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried many things but this is what worked.

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_embedded_jetty

Just be sure to include the appropriate libraries like weld-servlet, cdi-api, el-api and el-impl

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some docs on this a while back, if you an issues let me know.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html

Comment: Hello. I read your doc about jetty and weld and follow your instructions. I can deploy my webapp with weld on Jetty, but I can't get the jetty-maven-plugin working. Any tip? I post a question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848409/cdi-invalid-bean-archive-scanning-in-jetty-not-in-tomcat
Thankyou.