# CDI invalid bean archive scanning in Jetty (not in Tomcat)

Tags: java, maven, cdi, weld, maven-jetty-plugin

I thought I got the most about Weld and CDI but this assumption is always demonstrating false. This time I am facing a weird behavior about bean scanning. Everything (a multi-module maven project) runs fine in Tomcat, but I got problems when it runs in the Maven Jetty 9 plugin:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000033: Invalid bean archive scanning result - found multiple results with the same reference: /home/myuser/workspace/my-root-project/my-web-module/target/classes
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:329)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:170)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000033: Invalid bean archive scanning result - found multiple results with the same reference: /home/pezzati/workspace/GI-project/gs-service/target/classes
at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:96)
at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.createDeployment(WeldServletLifecycle.java:308)
at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:159)
at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
... 50 more
```

I searched a lot but I can't find so much about this error. Sadly I can even share poor things about this project. It looks like Jetty scans for beans twice, is that possible? Any help/tip about what this error could be about and how to track it down?

**UPDATE**
Here is a snippet of the pom.xml regarding Weld:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-integration-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

`jetty-maven-plugin` version is 9.4.6.v20170531. The webapp is a simple webapp. It deploy fine on a Jetty 9.4.6 where you activate the `cdi` module.

**UPDATE**
I read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html) and I add the weld-servlet artifact as plugin's dependency:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
  <configuration>
    <httpConnector>
      <port>${jetty.port}</port>
    </httpConnector>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
...
```

`web.xml` does not need any change, but I am facing the same result (weld servlet version match with jar version inside jetty's cdi module directory).

Comment: Found any solution for this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Dinesh sorry, no solution. I abandoned that project.

Comment: I'm thinking about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few problems with Maven Jetty plugin (mainly strange classloading issues). The plugin was even removed from Weld examples.

The error basically means that Weld found multiple bean archives referencing the same beans.xml.

I believe your application would work fine if deployed to a standalone Jetty. Also a reproducer application or at least some configuration info (Weld version, Jetty version, etc.) and deploymnet structure would be helpful.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I updated the question as you suggest.